# Plesk 12 sendmail issues

Tags: php, email, plesk

First of this is my server configuration:

> OS    CloudLinux Server 6.7 (Aleksei Gubarev)
>   Plesk version   12.0.18 Update #65,

And now this is my problem.

I have disabled sendmail via panel, and set outoging mail limit 50 e-mail per inbox. Everything was working fine till recently when we started to have issues with mails.

Despite sendmail being disabled this works pretty good in command line

> echo -e "To:test@mail.com \nSubject: Test mail from web\n\n Test mail from web via senmail\n" | sendmail -t -F root@web.domain.com

Php works fine to, via php script despite php mail function being disabled in php ini (/opt/alt/php54/etc/php.ini)

> mail("test@mail.com","hello","test mail function");

And the worst thing is both of those methods ignore outgoing mail limit that is set in panel.

So basicly someone can hack one of our website and starts sending spam (which happened already).

**My questions are simple. How to disable sendmail permanently and how to disable php mail function on whole server.**

Ty in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the correct answer.

put `disable_functions = "mail, sendmail, mailx"` in `php.ini`.

If you use multiple php versions on server you have put that on every `php.ini` for each version.

In cloudlinux for instance location is

- `/opt/alt/php53/etc/php.ini`
- `/opt/alt/php54/etc/php.ini`